# I need to modify the function so the user input references the two different dictionaries

Tags: python

```
from random import *


easy_glossary = {'word1':'definition1',
                 'word2':'definition2',
                 'word3':'definition3'}

hard_glossary = {'word4':'definition4',
                 'word5':'definition5',
                 'word6':'definition6'}



def show_flashcard():

    random_key = choice(list(glossary))
    print('Define: ', random_key)
    input('Press return to see the definition')
    print(glossary[random_key])



 exit = False
 while not exit:
    user_input = input('Enter e to show an easy flashcard, h for hard and q to quit: ')
    if user_input == 'e':
        show_flashcard()
    elif user_input == 'h':
        show_flashcard()
    elif user_input == 'q':
    exit = True
    else:
        print('You need to enter either e, h or q.')
```

Comment: Hi, you can't just copy-paste your homework questions here. If you want help, please edit your question to indicate what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to try something like this

```
from random import *


easy_glossary = {'word1':'definition1',
                 'word2':'definition2',
                 'word3':'definition3'}

hard_glossary = {'word4':'definition4',
                 'word5':'definition5',
                 'word6':'definition6'}


def show_flashcard(flashcard_type):
    if flashcard_type == 'e':
        glossary = easy_glossary
    if flashcard_type == 'h':
        glossary = hard_glossary

    random_key = choice(list(glossary))
    print('Define: ', random_key)
    input('Press return to see the definition')
    print(glossary[random_key])


 exit = False
 while not exit:
    user_input = input('Enter e to show an easy flashcard, h for hard and q to quit: ')
    if user_input == 'e':
        show_flashcard('e')
    elif user_input == 'h':
        show_flashcard('h')
    elif user_input == 'q':
    exit = True
    else:
        print('You need to enter either e, h or q.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create something like this:

```py
hards = {
    'word1': 'def'
}
easy = {
    'word2': 'def2'
}

hardsandeasy = {}
for key in hards:
    hardsandeasy[key] = hards[key]
for key in easy:
    hardsandeasy[key] = easy[key]

#hardsandeasy will be the sum of the hard and easy dicts
```